# Hide product prices of items in stock in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I have the following code to show a red dot, instead of the price, when items are out of stock:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'theatre_child_woocommerce_get_price_html', 10, 2 );

function theatre_child_woocommerce_get_price_html( $price, $_product ) {

    if( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $price = '<div class="theatre_child_red_circle"></div>';
    }

    return $price;
}
```

My client now wants to hide the prices of items that are in stock. Clearly, if I use CSS to hide span.price, it hides the red circle as well.

How can I amend the code above to show a red circle for items out of stock, as well as hide prices for items that are in stock?

Answer (score 0):

The following will keep your red circle for Out of Stock items and will hide price for In stock items:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'theatre_child_woocommerce_get_price_html', 10, 2 );
function theatre_child_woocommerce_get_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    if( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $price = '<div class="theatre_child_red_circle"></div>';
    } else {
       $price = '';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.